# Is it possible to wipe Samsung S5 finger print scanner data from recovery

Tags: lock-screens, factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I heard Samsung S5 has finger print scanner to unlock screen. How reliable is this? If I perform a data wipe or factory reset via recovery will the finger print lock still works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the lockscreen is to prevent someone from accessing your data, which would be erased by performing a factory reset. A fingerprint scanner is not more secure than a password, it's only more convenient. A few cases where it falls short as a password are:

1. You leave your fingerprints everywhere
2. Its easier to obtain your fingerprints by force, than a password
3. Its harder to change your fingerprints than a password

And [Fingerprint lock in Samsung Galaxy 5 easily defeated by whitehat hackers](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/04/fingerprint-lock-in-samsung-galaxy-5-easily-defeated-by-whitehat-hackers/)